# How to handle require() and import in an app being migrated from NodeJS to TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

OK, I am close to giving up..

**TL;DR:** *Trying to migrate a nodejs app to typescript and failing miserably at the very start.*

Background:
So what I have is a simple NodeJS + Express backend that serves a couple of RESTful endpoints. Nothing fancy. So I was doing some refactoring and figured that I might as well use this time to learn proper TS.

Started by adding the necessary module imports (in package.json) and then changing some .js files to .ts. And this is where I got stuck.

What is killing me - I am used to using `require()` for fetching dependencies. That's how CommonJS works, and it works fine. For some reason though, TS decided that if I do a `require()` then I am certainly meaning to expose this new `const` as a global variable. Uhh okay, I guess. But the app doesnt run if I do:

```
ReferenceError: httpLoggerMiddleware is not defined
```

So I tried converting the whole thing to a module (a bunch of changes in package.json, in .eslintrc.json and some in .tsconfig.json). Then I've changed all the `requires` to `imports` and all the `module.exports` to `export { something }` and... it didnt work either.

Spent about 3-4 hours now searching the Internet for answers but to no avail. All of the answers are either too generic or deal with a different issue.

Edit - some code samples

### server.ts

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

[...]
app.use(httpLoggerMiddleware);
[...]
```

### HttpLoggerMiddleware.ts

```
const morgan = require("morgan");
const httpLoggerMiddleware = morgan("tiny");
module.exports = httpLoggerMiddleware;
```

---

Alternatively, if I try to do it the way I would in plain `CommonJS` approach, that is have one additional line in `server.ts`:

```
const httpLoggerMiddleware = require("./logger/HttpLoggerMiddleware");
```

then it produces the following error:

```
TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'httpLoggerMiddleware'.
```

---

Maybe I got the tsconfig.json config wrong?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "module": "CommonJS"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it more closely aligns with the advice given in [ask], especially the sections titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" and "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: Just use `import`. Seriously, *just use `import`*. Then compile your TS with your output set to commonjs and run the resulting JS on your server. This is not complicated. I'm not sure where you wondered off the path, but your instinct that this shouldn't/couldn't be this hard was correct. "I've changed all the requires to imports and all the module.exports to export { something } and... it didnt work either" please give us something more to work with than 'it didn't work'.

Comment: @JaredSmith is it ok if I compile to the same dir as the ts sources? in one of the TS tutorials it was advised to compile to a `built` dir, outside of `src` but when I initially tried that it resulted in more, even worse issues like files not being identified at all :/ ##Edit: yes, give me a couple of seconds to reproduce and add more details to the OP

Comment: You don't want to compile to the same dir (I mean, you might *want* that, but it's not going to necessarily work very well). All relative paths should be preserved, files not being found is weird. Can you create a minimal reproduction case?

Comment: Ok, so I just backtracked my steps and this is what I am getting - first it's asking me to `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json` and when I do change it, it goes like this `Unknown file extension ".ts" for ...\src\server.ts` where server.ts is the entrypoint for the whole app..

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with my tsconfig?? I've added it to the original post, for reference

Comment: ?? Are you trying to run the typescript directly in node without compiling it first? Those sound like *node.js runtime errors*, not typescript compiler errors. Can you include the exact shell commands you're using?

Comment: I am compiling it, my IDE does that for me.. You see how confusing this is for me. Like any option I try I end up hitting another wall

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243178/discussion-between-alex-and-jared-smith).